# How to connect to the Oracle 11g that I have just installed in my laptop?

Tags: oracle11g

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\my_laptop_name>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 19-JAN-2016 02:57
:19

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                19-JAN-2016 02:35:39
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 21 min. 41 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         g:\app\my_laptop_name\diag\tnslsnr\my_laptop_name-laptop\listener\
alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=my_laptop_name-laptop)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl.2.12.151" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.2.12.151" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\Users\my_laptop_name>
```

Now, my question is, what should I write in this dialog box of SqlDeveloper?

[image]

And, also, looks like I forgot my username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter following:

```
hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: orcl

Username: whatever user you activated. Did you activate hr?
Password: password you supplied
```

In case you have not activated any users so far, and want to login as sys, then

```
username: sys as sysdba password: specify password you selected for sys
```

Once you're logged in as sys, you can activate other users.

Answer (score 1):

So, **Connection name** is whatever you want to "bookmark" the connection; for **username** and **password** you should try to google "`oracle11g default user and password`" or it's what you choose when installing oracle11g; **hostname**: so if you are running on the same machine it's `localhost`; **port** is written in that log text, go search it; **SID**: to be honest I don't know what it is but I'll make it easy on this one, it's `orcl`.

Next time try to give google a try. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Dont want to sound rude, but you could have landed on an excellent link on your first google search :)

I am sharing with you the link for the same. Please go through the same for a complete understanding  -

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html